# Multiple SKU Time Series Forecasting Using Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I was trying to recreate a code for Multiple Time Series Forecasting using Facebook Prophet (https://medium.com/grabngoinfo/3-ways-for-multiple-time-series-forecasting-using-prophet-in-python-7a0709a117f9), I was partially successful at this. But unfortunately the output they are generating is a time series which predicts forecast on a day to day basis but my time series input data is on month on month basis.

The Dataset I am using for this is:

```
{'Date': {0: '2019-01-01', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-01', 3: '2019-04-01', 4: '2019-05-01', 5: '2019-06-01', 6: '2019-07-01', 7: '2019-08-01', 8: '2019-09-01', 9: '2019-10-01', 10: '2019-11-01', 11: '2019-12-01', 12: '2020-01-01', 13: '2020-02-01', 14: '2020-03-01', 15: '2020-04-01', 16: '2020-05-01', 17: '2020-06-01', 18: '2020-07-01', 19: '2020-08-01', 20: '2020-09-01', 21: '2020-10-01', 22: '2020-11-01', 23: '2020-12-01', 24: '2021-01-01', 25: '2021-02-01', 26: '2021-03-01', 27: '2021-04-01', 28: '2021-05-01', 29: '2021-06-01', 30: '2021-07-01', 31: '2021-08-01', 32: '2021-09-01', 33: '2021-10-01', 34: '2021-11-01', 35: '2021-12-01', 36: '2022-01-01', 37: '2022-02-01', 38: '2022-03-01', 39: '2022-04-01', 40: '2022-05-01', 41: '2022-06-01', 42: '2022-07-01', 43: '2022-08-01', 44: '2022-09-01'}, 'XYZ|419': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 791, 11: 833, 12: 478, 13: 343, 14: 543, 15: 560, 16: 427, 17: 302, 18: 391, 19: 279, 20: 405, 21: 580, 22: 824, 23: 767, 24: 1102, 25: 1000, 26: 1032, 27: 668, 28: 540, 29: 477, 30: 353, 31: 427, 32: 28, 33: 2, 34: 914, 35: 718, 36: 44, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0}, 'XYZ|426': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 29, 18: 374, 19: 330, 20: 402, 21: 1005, 22: 1533, 23: 1582, 24: 1824, 25: 1168, 26: 193, 27: 895, 28: 613, 29: 651, 30: 267, 31: 233, 32: 135, 33: 173, 34: 564, 35: 789, 36: 343, 37: 275, 38: 383, 39: 181, 40: 96, 41: 499, 42: 53, 43: 84, 44: 23}, 'XYZ|465': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 44, 18: 292, 19: 240, 20: 364, 21: 806, 22: 1110, 23: 1232, 24: 1207, 25: 753, 26: 571, 27: 731, 28: 0, 29: 174, 30: 0, 31: 23, 32: 86, 33: 31, 34: 559, 35: 857, 36: 316, 37: 217, 38: 182, 39: 93, 40: 50, 41: 323, 42: 42, 43: 48, 44: 23}, 'XYZ|489': {0: 481, 1: 179, 2: 295, 3: 187, 4: 180, 5: 78, 6: 535, 7: 164, 8: 172, 9: 340, 10: 495, 11: 445, 12: 469, 13: 230, 14: 163, 15: 187, 16: 222, 17: 147, 18: 154, 19: 140, 20: 194, 21: 379, 22: 402, 23: 533, 24: 659, 25: 545, 26: 269, 27: 277, 28: 187, 29: 4, 30: 80, 31: 149, 32: 129, 33: 192, 34: 396, 35: 446, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0}, 'XYZ|457': {0: 181, 1: 80, 2: 74, 3: 150, 4: 665, 5: 187, 6: 335, 7: 238, 8: 149, 9: 281, 10: 696, 11: 440, 12: 619, 13: 349, 14: 310, 15: 396, 16: 251, 17: 202, 18: 165, 19: 176, 20: 166, 21: 249, 22: 167, 23: 364, 24: 411, 25: 327, 26: 326, 27: 396, 28: 6, 29: 107, 30: 177, 31: 136, 32: 6, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0}}
```

I am unable to get the output frequency from a day to day basis to Month on Month basis and also the output is churning out -ve values, Can someone please help me out to point out what is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from prophet import Prophet
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import time

df = pd.read_excel ('Sample_Data.xlsx')
print (df)
df = df.reset_index()

Dataframe = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Date',value_vars=['XYZ|419','XYZ|426','XYZ|465','XYZ|489','XYZ|457'])
SKU_List = ['XYZ|419','XYZ|426','XYZ|465','XYZ|489','XYZ|457']

Dataframe.columns = ['ds','SKU','y']
Dataframe.head()
Dataframe.info()
group_by_SKU = Dataframe.groupby('SKU')
type(group_by_SKU)
group_by_SKU.describe()
group_by_SKU.groups.keys()

def train_and_forecast(group):
    m=Prophet()
    
    m.fit(group)
    
    future=m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
    forecast=m.predict(future)[['ds','yhat','yhat_lower','yhat_upper']]
    forecast['SKU'] = group['SKU'].iloc[0]
    
    return forecast[['ds', 'SKU', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper', 'yhat_lower']]
    
start_time=time()

for_loop_forecast = pd.DataFrame()

for SKU in SKU_List:
    group = group_by_SKU.get_group(SKU)
    forecast = train_and_forecast(group)
    for_loop_forecast=pd.concat((for_loop_forecast,forecast))
    
print('The time used for the for-loop forecast is ', time()-start_time)
for_loop_forecast*
```

This is the output for after loading the excel

[image]

This is the output after melting the data frame

[image]

This is the output after DataFrame.info()

[image]

This is the final output after the model is fit, as you guys can see this output is predicted on a day to day basis and also the yhat is throwing "-ve" results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make_future_dataframe creates a new dataframe called future for the forecasting. periods=15 means that we will forecast for 15 days of data because the default frequency is daily data.

To use a different frequency, we can specify the freq option. For example, future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=15, freq='MS') means that we are forecasting for the next 15 months.

In your example, you are using 10 data points to predict 365 data points, which is not likely to give reasonable predictions. I suggest increasing the number of records for the model and decreasing the number of time periods to predict, for example, you can use 365 data points to build the model and predict 10 data points.

Hopefully this helps. Thank you for reading my tutorial.

Comment: The m.make_future_dataframe(periods=15, freq='MS') is now producing the Month on Month forecast but the forecast doesn't make much any sense. 
I have increased the training data has been increased to 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Aug-2022, so there is 3 years worth of data and for some reason, the forecast (yhat) is starting from 01-Jan-2019 onwards itself, much like in the above image, when it should start from 01-09-2022 as that is the beginning of forecasting time frame and more over there are so many negative values which makes forecast unreliable. Can you please share your opinion.

Comment: Prophet model predictions include data points for both the training time period and the prediction time period, so the yhat start date is correct. The prediction values are not expected probably because the model needs tuning. You can try to add more predictors (https://medium.com/grabngoinfo/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-with-seasonality-and-holiday-effect-using-prophet-in-python-d5d4150eeb57) and/or tune the hyperparameters (https://medium.com/grabngoinfo/hyperparameter-tuning-and-regularization-for-time-series-model-using-prophet-in-python-9791370a07dc).

Comment: can we do hyperparameter tuning for one model which predicts time series data that is not similar to each other? Is this even possible, don't we do hyperparameter tuning based on the history on one time series and how do we make hyperparameter tuning decisions when we have different TS history, is this possible?

Comment: If there are only 5 SKUs, it is feasible to tune hyperparameters for each SKU separately. If there are thousands of SKUs, then you can check the distribution of the performance matrix. Besides Prophet, you can try other time series algorithms and see if there is an algorithm with better performance.

Comment: I have about 300-500 SKU's which I need to forecast, what forecasting models would you recommend, I tried to replicate the function which you created here for forecasting using Holt Winter and Sarimax, but I encountered errors, Have you written any article where you use other models to forecast multiple time series, if so could you please share a link, that would be helpful.
I could also notice, in the code which you shared above the start date was spot on, it started on the exact date in which it was supposed to start, shouldn't there be an option to set the start date for forecasting

Comment: Prophet forecasting automatically includes all the dates for visualization purposes. You can get only the forecast part by slicing the data and only keep the forecasted part. I plan to write tutorials using more modeling algorithms in the near future, so stay tuned.